# Get access to the enum to change the map style UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, mapkit

I'm trying to change a map view (style) from default to satellite. I have only one button with toggle action.
Here is my enum where I need to change mapView:

```
final class TripRouteView: UIView {
   let mapView = Subviews.mapView()
   let modeButton = Subviews.modeButton()
   let viewButton = Subviews.viewButton()
}

private enum Subviews {     
   static func mapView() -> MKMapView {         
      let mapView = MKMapView()         
      mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false         
      return mapView     
   } 
}
```

My function is to check if the button is pressed:

```
final class TripRouteViewController: UIViewController {

...

private let contentView = TripRouteView()

override func loadView() {
   view = contentView
}

@objc private func didTapOnViewButton() {
    var mapView = MKMapView()
    showingSatelliteMapView.toggle()
    if showingSatelliteMapView {
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    } else {
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    }
  }
}
```

So I could see a button in my app, and when I pressed it, I could see messages in consoles "1" and "2" because of my print command. But how to get access to the enum to change the map style?

Comment: We need to see more code. Where are you creating and saving the map view. One immediate problem I can see is that `didTapOnViewButton` is creating a new map view and changing its type. That new map view is not the one you are using

Comment: You are right. I created a new mapView instead of using mapView from the extension! @GeoffHackworth

Comment: What class is `didTapOnViewButton` in? If it is `TripRouteView` then just access your local property for the map view instead of creating a new one.

Comment: didTapOnViewButton -> TripRouteViewController @GeoffHackworth

Comment: Your button handler will need to access the map view that your `TripRouteView` has created to change its style (or add a method to `TripRouteView` that can be used to change it without exposing the map view to the view controller)

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask @GeoffHackworth

Comment: Then you need to show more code. Where is the view controller creating and storing the `TripRouteView`?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my mistake was creating a new `mapView` instead of accessing enum properties. The `didTapOnViewButton()` should look like this:

```
@objc private func didTapOnViewButton() {
     showingSatelliteMapView.toggle()
     if showingSatelliteMapView {
         contentView.mapView.mapType = .satellite
     } else {
         contentView.mapView.mapType = .standard
     }
}
```